# Help me find the verse that says all good praises / words belongs to Hashem

Tags: sources-mekorot, words

I was reading comments on a thread two weeks ago and I came across a verse that says all good praises / words only belongs to Hashem. I can't remember where I save the text, please help me find this verse. I can't recall what book it was. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you chose that tag? If so please edit your post to reflect.

Comment: I can't find the right tag for this question. I just like to show a verse to a friend that he cannot connect negative words to Hashem become of this verse. It says something like we should praise Hashem with all beautiful / highest descriptions.

Comment: I guess we’ll try our best, good luck

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can find is in the the poem from the High Holiday liturgy [HoAdereth VoHoEmunoh](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94) that has the stanza:

> הַשִּׁיר וְהַשֶּׁבַח - לְחַי עוֹלָמִים

> [All] songs and praises - [belong] to the Almighty

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following extract from the prayer, “Yishtabach” although it is not strictly a verse:

> כִּי לְךָ נָאֶה ה' אֱלהֵינוּ וֵאלהֵי אֲבותֵינוּ שִׁיר וּשְׁבָחָה.
> הַלֵּל וְזִמְרָה. עוז וּמֶמְשָׁלָה. נֶצַח גְּדֻלָּה וּגְבוּרָה.
> תְּהִלָּה וְתִפְאֶרֶת. קְדֻשָּׁה וּמַלְכוּת: בְּרָכות וְהודָאות
> מֵעַתָּה וְעַד עולָם:
>
> For to You is fitting, our God and the God of our forefathers, song
> and praise, hymn and psalm, strength and dominion, eternity, greatness
> and power holiness and kingship, blessing and acknowledgements from
> now and forever.